# How to chain IBM Data Connect Activities in a flow

Tags: ibm-cloud, dataconnect

I have defined several Activities in IBM Data Connect (on Bluemix) and would like to chain them together, e.g. one for copying a Cloudant DB to dashDB, another for refining the copied data - so forth and so on.

Can this be done? If yes - how.

Answer (score 0):

Data Connect doesn't currently support a way of chaining your activities together. However, you could make use of the current scheduling capabilities to arrange the activities to run in sequence. As the only current trigger mechanism we have is time, their successful operation would require you to leave enough time for each one to execute before the next activity in the chain.

I will find out for you if we have the kind of feature you're after on our roadmap.

Regards,

Wesley - 
IBM Bluemix Data Connect Engineering

Comment: Hi Wesley, thanks for the reply. The solution that I have currently in mind is to schedule the first task using Data Connect and then define the following actions using OpenWhisk, Nodejs and the Data Connect API.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Data Connect API to do the orchestration. See the documentation here https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/dataworks1/index.html

Regards,
Hernando Borda

IBM Bluemix Data Connect Product Manager